# Align TextViews to top of LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment, android-linearlayout, textview

I'm creating an app that has four different TextView inside a LinearLayout. 
The LinearLayout has a weight sum of 4 and every TextView has a weight of 1 (to make them with evenly width). 
My first problem is that two of the TextViews has a bigger height than the other two and this make them centered but I want them to be top aligned to the LinearLayout so all of the TextViews have a straight line.

My second problem is that one of the strings is longer than the width of the TextView, which makes that TextView go slightly downward (it is not even centered anymore and is outside of the LinearLayout parent, so all of the TextView width is not shown).

My code:

```
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
        LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        layout.setWeightSum(lessons);

        for (int i = 0; i < lessons; i++) {
            TextView text = new TextView(context);
            LayoutParams textParams = new LayoutParams((int) (0 * (context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density) + 0.5f),
                    (int) (length[i] * (context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density) + 0.5f), 1);
            text.setLayoutParams(textParams);

            System.out.println(length[i]);

            text.setPadding((int) (8 * (context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density) + 0.5f), 0, 0, 0);
            text.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white_text));
            text.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.class.getField(name[i]).getInt(null)));
            text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16);
            text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            text.setText(R.string.class.getField(name[i]).getInt(null));

            layout.addView(text);
        }

        week[day].addView(layout);
```

Comment: 2 advices .... 1-) move to RelativeLayout ,2-)use xml layout instead

Comment: @Muhannad Fakhouri I will test the RelativeLayout, but the xm thing is not a choice, since the layout need to be dynamic based on user choices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since every user only needs to see one of those TextViews based on which group they belong to I will make it a user setting and only show the correct TextView for that user.

Answer (score 0):

post the xml code... but it seems to me that you're not setting the height or width to 0dp (height if it's a vertical layout/width if horizontal)... also, make sure that all your textViews have the android:singleLine="true" attribute